# In canon, has a Jedi ever used the light side to kill a Sith?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

(Spoilers in the question)

In Disney canon, has a Jedi ever used only light side techniques/powers to kill a Sith?

Some battles I can think of that don't count:

- Obi-Wan defeats Darth Maul in *The Phantom Menace*, but Maul is shown to survive in *Clone Wars* and *Rebels*.
- Anakin kills Dooku in *Revenge of the Sith*, but he uses the dark side at Palpatine's goading.
- Obi-Wan kills General Grievous in *Revenge of the Sith*, but I don't think he's considered a Sith. (Correct me if I'm wrong about him being Sith, but back it up with canon citations, please.)

Questionable:

- Anakin kills Palpatine in *Return of the Jedi*, but it's questionable whether he counts as a Jedi here. If we have canon evidence that he didn't use any dark side techniques/powers, this would count.

Most other questionable/debatable instances are okay. Possible mitigating factors I can imagine:

- It might not be clear whether the person is a Jedi at the time of the kill. (Anakin was redeemed, at best, only *seconds* before killing Palpatine.)
- It might not be clear whether the Jedi used dark side powers. (Anakin killing Palpatine.)
- It might not be clear that the Sith is dead. This one doesn't have to be completely definitive, but try not to be too liberal here. I'm sure a lot of people thought Maul was dead until he showed up in *Clone Wars*, so prior to that, Obi-Wan defeating him on Naboo would have been a good example. But just falling off a ledge and someone looking over and not seeing them probably isn't enough by itself.

If any instances are not crystal clear, please just make sure you explicitly state the mitigating factors. I'm not looking to debate or give a strict set of rules about what counts and what doesn't. Just use some good judgment. Readers can decide for themselves.

I'm not interested in Legends here. I'm certain we can find examples in Legends books or games. This is about Disney canon only.

(It might be worth noting that while I've seen a little of *Clone Wars* and *Rebels*, I haven't seen much. So there might be obvious examples in those that I'm missing.)

Comment: Well, if Vader killed Anakin, and later Vader became Anakin when he redeemed himself, I suppose we could say that Anakin killed Vader....

Comment: Much like Jonah, I think that we can say that Luke killed Vader metaphorically using Light techniques.

Comment: @Jonah ...from a certain point of view :P

Comment: This currently has (Order) 66 views.

Comment: Disney canon references so much of the other story lines (and so often), it may be difficult to distinguish Disney from non-Disney in order to give you a concrete answer..

Comment: Could we spoiler tag things that are as recent as the end of season 2 of Rebels? :(

Comment: Anakin killed Palpatine/Sidious by physically lifting him and throwing him down a hole. I don't think he used Dark Side powers. Anakin probably would have survived if he used the Force at all.

Comment: @JeremyFrench I kind of figured that the whole question and answer would be so full of spoilers, you shouldn't read it. That's why there's a warning at the top of the question. But if there's some consensus around what should and shouldn't be spoiler tagged, I'd appreciate a suggested edit.

Comment: To be fair, Maul didn't just fall off a ledge. He fell off a ledge in two pieces. That's a much better reason to assume someone is dead than the ol' over-the-ledge movie trick.

Comment: IIRC in Anakin v. Dooku, all of Palpatine's goading occured *after* Anakin had won the fight. Even if proto-Vader killed Dooku with fear, anger, and hatred in his heart, all he did was move his arms. This was an example of a dark act. Something that further led Anakin down the path to the dark side. But I don't see how it can be considered a dark side **technique**.

Comment: Grievous was not a Sith. He was a general of the CIS who was a cyborg Kaleesh, and his lightsabers were trophies collected from Jedi he or his traps/droids killed. He was never a Sith, nor would he ever have the chance to become one due to his lack of force-sensitivity. He was very skilled in tactics and lightsaber combat.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Yes

There are only a few Sith in Disney canon. Most are ambiguous cases,  but with new information from *The Rise of Skywalker*, there is one definitive one.

### Plagueis

He was killed by his apprentice, Darth Sidious, who was certainly a Sith. So he doesn't count.

### Maul

Maul was killed by Obi-Wan Kenobi on Tatooine. Obi-Wan had not fallen to the dark side, so presumably he was using light side Force powers, as in all lightsaber combat. However, at this time, Maul was strictly speaking no longer a Sith Lord.

### Tyranus

Killed by Anakin, but Anakin was certainly being tempted to the Dark Side at the time.

> A starburst of clarity blossoms within Anakin Skywalker's mind, when
>   he says to himself: Oh. I get it, now and discovers that the **fear
>   within his heart can be a weapon, too**.
>
> It is that simple, and that complex. And it is final.
>
> Dooku is dead already. The rest is mere detail.
>
> ...
>
> The deck bucked as the cruiser absorbed a new barrage of torpedoes and
>   turbolaser fire. Dooku's severed staring head bounced along the deck
>   and rolled away, and Anakin woke up.
>
> "What—?"
>
> He'd been having a
>   dream. He'd been flying, and fighting, and fighting again, and
>   somehow, in the dream, he could do whatever he wanted. In the dream,
>   whatever he did was the right thing to do simply because he wanted to
>   do it. In the dream there were no rules, there was only power.
>
> And the
>   power was his.
>
> —*Revenge of the Sith*

### Bane

Bane *was* defeated by the Jedi, but there is no canon evidence that they did *not* use the Dark Side to defeat him. It doesn't seem likely, but there it is.

### Sidious

He was "killed" by Anakin Skywalker (*not* Darth Vader). It's unclear whether Anakin used any Dark Side techniques, but I don't think he did. His strength was granted by his suit and cybernetics. He seems to have merely picked up Sidious and thrown him into a pit.

> Palpatine struggled in the grip of Vader’s unfeeling embrace, his
>   hands still shooting bolts of malign energy out in all directions. In
>   his wild flailing, the lightning ripped across the room, tearing into
>   Vader. The Dark Lord fell again, electric currents crackling down his
>   helmet, over his cape, into his heart. Vader stumbled with his load to
>   the middle of the bridge over the black chasm leading to the power
>   core. He held the wailing despot high over his head, and with a final
>   spasm of strength, hurled him into the abyss.
>
> —*Return of the Jedi*

Far more clearly, he was killed by his grandchild, Rey. At that point she was by her own admission a Jedi, and was backed by the power of the spirits of past Jedi. With the help of this power, she reflected Palpatine's own lightning back at him, killing him. There is no indication that she drew on the dark side, and it is hard to get more defensive (and thus Jedi) than causing the dark side to consume itself.

So the answer is *yes*. Rey clearly counts; there may be other instances, but they are more ambiguous.

Comment: Could you clarify how we know that the Jedi defeated Bane? I assume this was mentioned in *Clone Wars*, but it would be good to reference it.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Actually, I'm not sure whether I should change that. It's from the official online Encyclopedia, which was succeeded by the Databank. Is that still canon?

Comment: Good answer, but isn't this still having to fall back on non-Disney canon?

Comment: @ouflak - Which part?

Comment: RE whether official online Encyclopedia is still canon: I have no idea. Sounds like a question you could ask, though. =)

Comment: @adamant mauls fate has already been revieled by now

Comment: @Thomas - Did you downvote for that? It hadn’t been when I wrote this answer.

Comment: This answer could be updated with latest info from Rebels.  BUT - I don't think Obi-wan vs Maul counts, since Maul was no longer a Sith at the time.

Comment: @Adamant No in all honesty I would never downvote answers because a new entry into a series outdates parts of it. In cases where I see that I just "pm" the ones who created the answer so that they can see (as I hate editing the answers of others). So no the downvote wasn't me

Comment: @Tim Sure about that? Maul never was thrown out of the Sith order he was just thought of as being death. (although there are some comments out there that Maul wasn't a true sith to start with and just an in between trainee as an assassin like ventress until Palpatine found a good true Sith candidate)

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I'm certain. Although Maul still used the dark side and his Sith training, he had renounced the Sith, and no longer considered himself one of them. He actually wanted vengeance against Sidious, and sought to end the Sith.

Comment: Darth Vader would be considered a sith in canon. While Anakin is ultimately redeemed, Darth Vader was still a sith for a time.

Comment: The Sidious Rey killed was his clone, not the same individual that Anakin killed on the second Death Star.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - It was his clone, *inhabited by the consciousness of Palpatine*. It was the same person, in a different body. Just like in the *Dark Empire* comics. It was not some clone with no connection to the original, like Rex with Jango Fett.

Answer (score 29):

Adamant's answer was right at the time he answered it, but with more recent episodes of Star Wars Rebels, the answer is a definitive **yes**.

> Maul flies to Tatooine to confront Obi Wan. Maul initiates a fight, but after a *very* brief exchange, Obi Wan delivers a fatal blow. Dying, Maul asks if Luke is the chosen one, which Obi Wan affirms. With his last breath Maul exclaims, "He will avenge us all!"

Comment: I was just thinking about deleting this question the other day. It's actually a pretty bad question. lol

Comment: @jpmc26 nah, it's not hurting anyone. Actually kind of surprised me because I hadn't thought about the fact that in the movies, there aren't really any examples of the good guys killing sith (that aren't resurrected in cartoons)

Comment: I updated the accepted answer to include this information.

Comment: @WilliamJackson I'm pretty sure that is bad form unless you want to make it a community answer

Comment: @TBear I thought that was *the point* of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @WilliamJackson The point of SE is not to duplicate information. When a new, more definitive answer is added, the OP is free to change their acceptance by clicking the check mark. Other than that, users are supposed to vote on the better answer and bring it to the top.

Comment: @WilliamJackson - There's a related meta here; [What is the protocol when another user incorporates my answer into an existing answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11349/what-is-the-protocol-when-another-user-incorporates-my-answer-into-an-existing-a). My take is that your actions (although without malice) were inappropriate.

Comment: @WilliamJackson that's not how this stack works, and as far as I'm aware not how other stacks work. This answer is different to the initially accepted answer, as at the time of the answer was one thing and has since changed. The "accepted answer" isn't the only answer and multiple answers are encouraged. New information doesn't get continually added into the first answer, otherwise the average of 2.5 answers per question to get out of beta would be *POINTLESS*. Although sometimes users will edit the original with the info they have found, they are not obliged to.

Comment: This answer is kind of wrong, anyway. In order to be correct, the answerer would need to provide evidence that the dark-side user in this scene was still a Sith. As far as I can tell, there are only two Sith at the time of this event (Rule of Two after all), and neither one of them was involved in this scene.

Comment: @Ellesedil I thought about that actually, and decided for the more succinct answer, but I believe you may still count Maul as a Sith. The rule of two is not a law of the Force, but a practice of the Sith Lords. Maul was trained by a Sith, wields the dark side of the Force, and accesses the Sith temples. He is a rival Sith to Sidious, but he is still a Sith. He was actively trying to make Ezra his apprentice as well, to complete the rule of two.

Comment: I disagree with most of that. Maul is certainly trying to follow the Sith ways, but he's most definitely on the junior varsity team while Sidious is running the professional league. This scene shows the huge disparity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hc3vSUVwoyY  It also includes some interesting counter points."Remember, the first and only reality of the Sith: there can only be two and you are no longer my apprentice. You have been replaced." Also, the Inquisitors are trained by the Sith, but I wouldn't consider them to be Sith either.

Comment: @Ellesedil There seems to be some debate on the subject, but this would be a great follow up question.

Comment: Well, if there's debate specifically on the Inquisitors, then you have Kanan defeating the High Inquisitor as a possible answer. But I'd probably downvote that since I'm pretty certain considering Inquisitors as Sith would violate Sith principles and are simply trained dark-side Force users. There's still mitigating factors, though, since the High Inquisitor didn't actually die from any direct action Kanan took, but simply decided to die after Kanan forced him into an unwinnable situation.

Comment: The inquisitors are like ventress and she wasn't a Sith. Sith themselves are trained more specifically not only the dark side but also the Sith way. There was some discussion in the past if Maul was more like ventress to start with or a true sith. That aside "His" Problem is like the Jedi and former jedi problem. The sith count the later still as jedi though (if they didn't turn sith). So Technically even if cast out of the order of the Sith Maul still counted as a Sith (from a JEdis perspective) as he didn't repent and join the Jedi order.

Comment: @jpmc26 you can't delete a question that has an answer anyway (tried that in the past with a very bad question of mine and learned it there).

Comment: @Ellesedil "If any instances are not crystal clear, please just make sure you explicitly state the mitigating factors." ;) A minutia war was something I had hoped to avoid, not that I did a great job of that myself in the question. Maul is *certainly* worth bringing up. Not sure what I'm going to do with the accept; still thinking about it.

Comment: @jpmc26 Maul is worth mentioning, yes. But he's not the correct answer since he's not a member of the Sith anymore. If Asohka had killed Vader when they fought, she wouldn't be the correct answer either because she's not a Jedi, despite her training and close affiliation. Part of the problem, I think, is that your question uses some specific labels, and those labels have specific meaning. This answer tries to redefine one of those labels (Sith). A question strictly about light/dark side would probably have been more simple.

Comment: @Ellesedil Whether it's incorrect is a matter of opinion on whether that minutia matters, something on which people can reasonably disagree.